# Hyperlink in Beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref, external-files, links, viewers

I have used `hyperlink(say fig.pdf)` for my presentation in main pdf. In the `fig.pdf` I have again used `hyperlink` to main document. But my problem is when I  come back to main document its starting from first page. I should come back to the slide where I left. In ubuntu document viewer its working fine but in the Acrobat Reader it always go to first page. Any settings which has to be done in Acrobat Reader?????

Answer (score 0):

Adobe reader allows you to specify parameters after the pdf where you can tell it which page you want it to open with a syntax similar to intra page link in `html`:

```
filename.pdf#page=<pagenum>
```

there are a lot more options available and you can get them from [this document](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) from the adobe website.

I do not know if other pdf readers will understand this syntax though.